# How to build ipa for ios from React native Expo using Windows 10?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have made a react native project, now I want to build the apk & ipa for that. For apk, I just run the following command-

> expo build:android

And it worked well. But when I run the command for ios -

> expo build:ios

It shows me the following error:

[image]

Is there any way to solve this using windows 10 or I just can't build the ipa from windows?

Comment: download the ubuntu from Microsoft store and run it once after you install it, that's it.

Comment: Will it make any changes in my system or cause any harm to windows after installing ubuntu?

Comment: No, it won't, because it's a subsystem.

Comment: Ok, thanks, it works. But another problem occurs- it requires the Apple id. Is there any way of getting ipa without apple id like the way I get apk without any id ?